# Macro with ## in @interface, what does it mean?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

What does it do, especially the `##` ?

```
#define CUSTOM_ARRAY_INTERFACE(classname) \
@interface classname ## Array : ConcreteMutableArray \
- (void) add:(classname*)obj;\
- (classname*) get:(int)index;\
@end\
```

What does `CUSTOM_ARRAY_INTERFACE(NSString)` generate then, this idea of mine doesn't even work

```
@interface NSString ## Array : ConcreteMutableArray
- (void) add:(classname*)obj;
- (classname*) get:(int)index;
@end
```

**?**

### Is a way to show to what code a macro would get expanded, without looking into assembler code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see preprocessor output for your file  the following way from Xcode menu:

- in **Xcode 4.6**: go to "Product" -> "Generate output" -> "Preprocessed File".
- in **Xcode 5**: go to "Product" -> "Perform Action" -> "Preprocess File".

For your macro example it produces the following code:

```
@interface NSStringArray : ConcreteMutableArray 
- (void) add:(NSString*)obj;
- (NSString*) get:(int)index;
@end
```

Answer (score 6):

The `##` is a macro concatenation operator, so that

```
CUSTOM_ARRAY_INTERFACE(Foo)
```

would concatenate `Foo` with `Array` and result in

```
@interface FooArray : ConcreteMutableArray 
- (void) add:(Foo*)obj;
- (Foo*) get:(int)index;
@end
```

Or

```
CUSTOM_ARRAY_INTERFACE(NSString)
```

would result in

```
@interface NSStringArray : ConcreteMutableArray 
- (void) add:(NSString*)obj;
- (NSString*) get:(int)index;
@end
```

---

It's worth noting that Objective-C now supports [lightweight generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID173), eliminating the need for the above pattern. For example, `NSArray` lets you specify the type of objects for the individual elements in the array, e.g.

```
NSArray <NSString *> *array = ...
```

Now the compiler knows that `array` is an array of strings without needing to declare a specific type for this. The compiler will know that the following is valid:

```
NSString *string = array[0];
```

But if you attempted to do something like:

```
NSNumber *number = array[0];
```

It would resulting in the following compile-time warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSNumber *' with an expression of type 'NSString *'.

Note, this is a "lightweight" generic. E.g. it merely results in compile-time warnings, but doesn't strictly enforce this at runtime like true generics in other languages (such as Swift).